# Mercurial - how to force author to ldap login on push?

Tags: mercurial

**My objective**: force author in my mercurial server to match with my ldap user.

**Explanation**:

1. I have my mercurial server. It use ldap authentification and autorisation from apache.
2. On a client desktop, i can clone/commit/push my repositories (i use my ldap creditential for that)

**Issue**:

1. The client commit on it desktop using the username he wants (exemple: mydummyusername)
2. When the client push, he must enter his ldap login/password (login john for example).
3. Then, when i look to my server using http, unfortunatly i see the author 'mydummyusername'. (Note: i expected to see the author 'john', 'mydummyusername' does not exist in the ldap)

**Ideas**:

1. writing a hook - not working using apache http (and my friend google told me that it only works with ssh urls :-/)
2. hgwebdir.cgi: trying to get ldap username using python (os.environ['REMOTE_USER']) and force to affect it to the mercurial object : not working (and i think bad idea)

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a bad idea.  In a DVS it's very normal for someone to pull changesets from one person and push them to another.  Or merge someone else's branch into theirs and then push changesets from both.

If you can't trust the people who have LDAP access to your system to not forge the author: on their commits you have organizational problems not technical ones.

(Also, your friend is wrong hooks work just fine on http and ssh)